# Google Sheets IF/THEN statement noob

Tags: formula

I would like to create a formula that will check if a name exists in a column against a number of tasks, and for *each row where that name is found* cross reference that with various statuses and summarize the status.

So take the example below, if I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of tasks assigned against a bunch of names at various states of completion (Columns A&B), I would like to (in a different tab, same tab, somewhere else, doesn't matter) list out those names and get a general status (Columns C&D). Rules are simple: if any tasks assigned to them is in progress, their entire task list is in progress. If all are complete, it's complete. If all are unassigned, it's unassigned. If any are complete and remainder unassigned, it's in progress.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Complete | Bob | In progress |
| Bob | Unassigned | Peter | Unassigned |
| Bob | In progress | John | In progress |
| Peter | Unassigned |  |  |
| Peter | Unassigned |  |  |
| John | In progress |  |  |
| John | In progress |  |  |
| John | In progress |  |  |

I've tried entering in a formula in D1 like =IF(AND(ISTEXT(SEARCH(C1,A:A)),ISTEXT(SEARCH("Complete"))),"Complete","In progress") and didn't know how to move forward.